# Extract value of property from object in a Set?

Tags: javascript, typescript, ecmascript-6

For the example, `SomeItem` is the model for an object (would be modeled as an interface in Typescript or you can just imagine that there is an item with the form of `SomeItem` if we are in untyped land.

Say I have a `Set`: `mySet = new Set([{item: SomeItem, selected: true}, ...])`.

And I want to check if `itemA: SomeItem` is selected or not.

What is the cleanest way to do this?

This did not work:

```
const isSelected = mySet.has({item: itemA, selected: true});
```

Nor did this:

```
const isSelected = Array.from(mySet).includes({item: itemA, selected: true});
```

I'm assuming the above two did not work because it is trying to compare the objects by reference, rather than value.

This does work:

```
let isSelected: boolean;
mySet.forEach(state => {
  if (state.item === itemA) {
    isSelected = state.selected;
  }
});
```

But my gut tells me there is a correct way to do this.

So,
**How do I extract the value of a property of an object in a Set?**

Comment: Are you sure you want to be using a `Set` here? This looks like a job for `Map`. A `Set` returns iterables, a `Map` stores key value pairs, hashed

Comment: Yep, just had that realization myself and came back here to remove the question. Debating whether to leave it up out of curiosity though -- what if the object had three or more properties?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comparing two objects with the same properties returns true only if they have the same reference, I would suggest to compare their properties as the properties are primitive values..

The array some method can be used to filter if the set contains an specific object

```js
let mySet = new Set([{item: 'SomeItem', selected: true}]);
let itemA = "SomeItem";
let isSelected =  Array.from(mySet).some(element => element.item === itemA);
console.log(isSelected);
```

Comment: While Sterling's answer is what I will implement in my code, your answer directly answers the question, so I am accepting it.

Answer (score 2):

Let's take a look at it this way, `Set`s mainly return an iterable. Sure, they're hashed in order, as is a `Map`, but from the looks of your data structure, a `Map` would benefit you more here.

```
const x = new Set([
    { "foo": 1, selected: true },
    { "bar": 1, selected: false },
    { "baz": 1, selected: false },
    { "barf": 1, selected: false },
]);
```

Now, to get what you're looking for, you'll need as you did, convert to an array using `Array.from` (or `[...x]` spread it) and iterate, finding they key.

Now, as a Map:

```
const y = new Map();
y.set("foo", { selected: true });
y.set("bar", { selected: false });
y.set("baz", { selected: false });
y.set("barf", { selected: false });
```

With this, you simply change the structure slightly to give `item1` or whatever you use the Map key, and set whatever elements you want.

```
y.has("foo"); // true
y.get("foo").selected; //true
```

So if you wanted here, it's much easier to grab the iterable key name and get which Map index has the property you want

Comment: This makes sense. I hadn't thought about using an object as the value for the Map. So a Map really is the way to go, no matter how many properties are tied to the item. Thanks for your time.

Comment: I'm glad I could help! You should give @RenzoCC an upvote too, his answer is very good and directly answers your question.

Comment: Ah, noble of you to direct my attention there, I just hadn't seen his answer. While your solution is the one I will be implementing for my use case, his answer does indeed directly answer my question, so I had to accept it. Thanks again.

Comment: That's quite alright! Helping is more important than the checkmark :)